# Error al crear Trigger en Postgres

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Tengo un problema a la hora de crear mi trigger en PostgreSQL, me da un error de sintaxis pero la verdad no se que pueda ser, ya he revizado mi cidigo y creo pensar que esta bien.
El código es este:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER ActualizarAlmacen before insert
      on detallecompra for each row

      DECLARE mp_id int=0;
      DECLARE cant int=0;
      DECLARE cantidadIA int=0;

       BEGIN
        mp_id=new.materiaprima_id;
        cant=new.cantidad;
        cantidadIA=(select cantidad from inventario_almacen where    materiaprima_id=mp_id);
        cantidadIA=cantidadIA+cant;
        update inventario_almacen set cantidad=cantidadIA where materiaprima_id=mp_id;
       END;
```

el error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los triggers en PostgreSQL debes crear una función trigger y luego el trigger que llama a esa función con tu código de negocio adentro

Por ejemplo

```
CREATE TRIGGER ActualizarAlmacen before insert
on detallecompra for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE funciontrigger();
```

Y antes debes tener definida la función trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funciontrigger() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
   mp_id int=0;
   cant int=0;
   cantidadIA int=0;
BEGIN
    mp_id=new.materiaprima_id;
    cant=new.cantidad;
    cantidadIA=(select cantidad from inventario_almacen 
     where    materiaprima_id=mp_id);
    cantidadIA=cantidadIA+cant;
    update inventario_almacen set cantidad=cantidadIA 
     where materiaprima_id=mp_id;
  Return new;-- el return es muy importante
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Excelente, desconocía lo del tema de la función que se relaciona con el trigger- Gracias!.